# segmentation fault (core dumped) when I try cout a const char *[i], what is the issue?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++, coredump

g++ compiler says:

> segmentation fault (core dumped)

when this code is running:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

const char *constantChars[3], *variableChars[3];
long int numbers[3];

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    constantChars[i] = "hello number: ";
    numbers[i] = i;
    variableChars[i] = (const char *) numbers[i];

    cout<<constantChars[i]<<variableChars[i]<<endl;
}

return 0;}
```

it crash when `cout<<variableChars[i]<<endl` in my for loop.

Comment: The issue is here: `for(int i=0; i<4; i++)` your index goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
variableChars[i] = (const char *) numbers[i];
```

to:

```
variableChars[i] = (const char *)(&numbers[i]);
```

Comment: And as  πάντα ῥεῖ said, you have too big range for "for" loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with length of the arrays that you have declared. You have set the length to be 3 so it should be used for index from 0 to 2 whereas in your program you are using index from 0 to 3.

Just increase the length of all the arrays to 4, it will solve your problem.

Change:

```
const char *constantChars[3], *variableChars[3];
long int numbers[3];
```

to:

```
const char *constantChars[4], *variableChars[4];
long int numbers[4];
```